# how to tell eve REST framework to use different mongodb collection instead of resource name as collection name

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, eve

Generally if we doesn't specify value for 'source' fieid in the DOMAIN configuration, python eve framework will create the mongodb collection as resource name.

But if want to create mongodb collection with different name instead of resource name, what is the eve configuration i need to change ?

Best Regards,
Narendra

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://python-eve.org/config.html#advanced-datasource-patterns):

> `source`: Name of the database collection consumed by the resource. If omitted, the resource name is assumed to also be a valid collection name.

So, it looks like `datasource.source` is the setting you are looking for. Something like this:

```
endpoint = {
    'datasource': {
        'source': "mycollectioname"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @NicolaIarocci Suppose I want to group my documents (say name students) based on some factor (say institution) and put all students of an institution in a collection (say students_<institution>) for some very specific reason (business). I was thinking if you have a way to specify multiple 'source's under data source or multiple 'datasource's under endpoint and choose dynamically.

Comment: Thanks nicola for your reply. I would like to know how can tell eve framework to use different collection name instead of default mongo db collection name using any of the eve framework hooks